# angular-cli : Unable to find ngconfig.json

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-cli, node-modules

I'm working on AngularJS project. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.
When I run **ng serve** command in the project directory, it is throwing below error,

```
[12:38:02 PM UTC] ERR! Unable to find ngconfig.json , make sure you are inside ngcli project ✖
TRACE {
    "err": {}
}
```

Angular-cli is installed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `angular-cli` is designed to work with Angular 2 and above version. It doesn't work with AngularJS projects.

Answer (score 1):

By AngularJS i presume that you mean the Angular Version 1.x.x, The CLI that you have (@angular/cli on npm) is built for projects having Angular Version 2+.x.x which means it wouldn't run on the version of angular you are using.